# Regex function to look for a character just on part of the string

Tags: regex, genexus

I need help to build a regex rule to find some `[` on a text file.

Here is a sample of te text. It is a Json, but I can't use it as it is because of limitation of the program I'm using.

```
{
    "event":[
        "ONIMBOTMESSAGEADD"
    ],
    "data[BOT][123][BOT_ID]":[
        "123"
    ]
}
```

I need to find a regex that matches the line `"data[BOT][123][BOT_ID]":[` and find all `[` on it. The objectve is to replace it by an underscore so I would end up with something like this:

```
{
    "event":[
        "ONIMBOTMESSAGEADD"
    ],
    "data_BOT_123_BOT_ID":[
        "123"
    ]
}
```

I can't just remove all special characters because this would destroy the json structure.

I found a way to select each one of the lines that need to be corrected with the rule below, but I was not able to apply another rule over the result. I don't know how to do it.

```
pattern = (("data\[[a-zA-Z]+]\[[0-9]+]\[([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)\]":\[)|("data\[[A-Z]+]\[([A-Z]+(_|)[A-Z]+)\]":\[)|("data\[[A-Z]+]\[([A-Z]+(_|)[A-Z]+(_|)[A-Z]+)\]":\[))
```

Any ideas on how to solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Parse the JSON, then apply a RegEx to the keys.

Comment: That is the problem. I can't parse the Json. I'm using Genexus and It doesn't allows key names like these "data[BOT][123][BOT_ID]" so, it's impossible to parse.
I have to remove the problematic characters before doing anithing...

Comment: Looks like this Genexus [supports the `\G` anchor](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4606,Regular+Expressions+%28RegEx%29) which lets continue where a previous match ended. It is used to chain matches to some start point. Please check if it the following subsitution works: Replace `(?:\G(?!^)|("data))[\]\[]+([^:"\]\[]*)\]?` with `$1_$2` ([see this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/0eAkAe/3))

Answer (score 0):

Replacing weird `data*` key by only `data`:

```
jq '.["data"] = .[keys[0]] | del(.[keys[1]])' file
{
  "event": [
    "ONIMBOTMESSAGEADD"
  ],
  "data": [
    "123"
  ]
}
```